# "source" not working in bash shell while "." is on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bash, 20.04, python3, virtualenv

I have a virtualenv called `env` on Ubuntu 20.04, it was made using the system python installation (`python3 -m virtualenv env`).

I used `source env/bin/activate` and got a prompt prepended with `(env)` but `which python3` still gives `/urs/bin/python3`.

I used `deactivate` to exit, then tried `. env/bin/activate`, after which `which python3` points to the virtual environment python location as expected.

I'm using bash, and it was my understanding that `.` was an alias for `source` in bash, so why the different behavior?

Comment: It’s the other way around, source is actually a synonym provided by bash (and some other shells) for the POSIX standard . command

Comment: @ADDB That sounds like an answer if you can show the proof of that.

Comment: @ThomasWard https://ss64.com/bash/source.html

Comment: That does not explain why it would work with `.` and not in `source`. Both are internal commands to bash, so one would expect them to act exactly identical.